# How can I have a dynamic image show when someone clicks the Facebook Like button and Posts to Facebook?

Tags: image, facebook, post, dynamic, facebook-like

Currently, when someone 'likes' a link and creates a Facebook post (via the like button), it will only grab the one image that I specify in the meta tag (via the og:image property).

What is the best way to allow people to post a dynamic image with dynamic description? In my case, I have several items (with image & description) listed on a page that the user should be able to 'like' and post on their wall. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Change the meta tag on click: use this example and modify it to your needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Title Of Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick='$("title").html("Changed Dynamically");'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't FB have to crawl the site to get the updated image? I'm not sure that would work.